# With Angular Reactive Forms, is it possible to have separate 'updateOn's for each validator?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have field that is both required and has a max length. If the user goes over the max length and moves on to another field, I want to show an error. However, if the user clicks on the field and types nothing then clicks off the field, I do not want to show a required error. The field is marked as required with an asterisk so it seems a bit overkill to also show an error saying "this field is required." I only want to show required errors on submit.

Unfortunately, it seems like Angular only lets you set updateOn at the field and group level. I can't find a way to have two different validators on the same field. Is this possible?

Comment: Provide some code and question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

you just need to do it in template:

```
<div class="error-message" *ngIf="ctrl.errors?.required && form.submitted">Required!></div>
<div class="error-message" *ngIf="ctrl.errors?.maxLength">Over max!></div>
```